# Add Google Plus link to head

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to add a Google Plus html tag via direct linking (see [here](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1713826?p=link_page_to_website&rd=1)) to my head but can't get it to work. What I'm trying is this inside my template.php file:

```
$googleplus = array(
    '#tag' => 'a',
    '#attributes' => array(
        'rel' => 'publisher',
        'href' => 'https://plus.google.com/+MyPage'
    )
);
drupal_add_html_head($googleplus, 'googleplus');
```

Nothing shows up for me. Is there a better/working way of doing this?

Comment: Where are you adding that? In template.php, `hook_preprocess_html` should work there.

Comment: @DavidThomas Doing it in preprocess_html puts it in the body tag, not the head

Comment: that's incorrect. hook_preprocess_html is for html.tpl.php which is the html wrapper including the head section of the document.

Answer (score 3):

Create block and place in Header Top. Go to Structure -> Block -> Add Block, then in Block body, write custom HTML. **Below block body, Text format should be in "FULL HTML" to display the image.**

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/.." target="_blank"><img src="YOURIMAGE" width="64" height="64"></a>
```

I think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this from a google search, and what I think you want to do is add a LINK or an A tag to the head section of your html page to tie together your Google+ page and your website..

This worked for me in template.php - remember to clear cache:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $googleplus = array(
   '#tag' => 'link', 
   '#attributes' => array(
     'href' => 'https://plus.google.com/GOOGLEPLUSACCOUNT', 
     'rel' => 'publisher',
    ),
  );
 drupal_add_html_head($googleplus, 'googleplus');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like J singha said, create a block (full html) and as body you paste a the link google gave you. After you have submitting, you will see a Google+ link appear on the place where you have placed your block.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate answer from J Singha. If you want to support an answer is better to upvote tu right answer instead of add the same answer.